# Style elements keep missing in chrome web inspector

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I use chrome all the time when developing my sites, although recently when inspecting elements randomly the style section of the editor will disappear and just show me the padding border and margin section and not the actual style of elements anymore. I've attached a picture of what happens. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: This is a bug; feel free to file one on [crbug.com](http://crbug.com) if you still experience this issue.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm getting it as well.. 2 years later!